# What is the purpose of the new Array(9) syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I can't use `.map` on an array created by the Array-constructor with a set length:

```js
// create an array with 9 empty elements
let array = new Array(9);
// assign an array to each of the array's elements
array = array.map(() => new Array(1, 2, 3));

console.log(array);
```

One way to achieve the desired effect by using a for loop:

```js
// create an array with 9 empty elements
let array = new Array();
// assign an array to each of them
for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  array.push(new Array(1, 2, 3));
}

console.log(array)
```

Why can't `.map` be used on an array with `empty` placeholders? What is the purpose of the `Array(3)` - syntax?

Comment: The purpose of the `Array(3)` syntax is to make a *sparse array* and be generally confusing. Don’t use the array constructor for anything. (`new Array()` and `new Array(1, 2, 3)` should be `[]` and `[1, 2, 3]`.)

Comment: You can use `map` in a sparse array. But what you are creating with your mapping in the first example is an array of 9 `undefined` elements.

Comment: Well explained here: https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript. Summary: there's simply never a case in Javascript where it would be useful to create a `new Array(x)` with a predefined length

Comment: you have "let array =" twice, the second time you should remove the "let"

Comment: You can still use `Array.from(new Array(3), (value, index) => (`…`))`, though that’s possible with `Array.from({length: 3}, (value, index) => (`…`))` as well.

Comment: you are redefining `array` second time. see the using of `let` twice

Comment: Why *not* use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `new Array(n)` to create a sparse array, an array with gaps, with the length of `n`. According to MDN article about [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> Due to the algorithm defined in the specification if the array which
>   map was called upon is sparse, resulting array will also be sparse
>   keeping same indices blank.

To solve that, you can use [Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), to fill the sparse array with a value (even `undefined` will do), and then you can map it with whatever you want.

```js
// create an array with 9 empty elements
const array = new Array(9);
// assign an array to each of the array's elements
const result = array
  .fill()
  .map(() => [1, 2, 3]);

console.log(result);
```